# Balancing Words

Tags: pattern, word-sequence

Many words are balanced, but most are not.
All of the following are examples of balanced words

**GOLD
LEMONS
UNCOOKED
BORDERLINE
LILLIPUTIANS
COUNTERBALANCE
PREDETERMINATION**

while none of the following are

**GEMS
ORANGE
DIGESTED 
UNDENIABLE
UNNOTICEABLE
COUNTERMEASURE
UNCOMPROMISINGLY**

Only one the following is a balanced word; which one?

BACKGAMMON, CHECKERS, CHESS, CRIBBAGE, DOMINOES

Comment: I found all but one of the bold words above are balanced. Surely I was wrong. :p

Comment: @LaBird I just double checked and I don't think there's any error, perhaps you had a typo in transcription or something?

Comment: I didn't mean you made an error, actually I just believe my reasoning is far too simple: I just found all the bold words contain even number of letters except "CHESS". So I think it is unbalanced. :p

Comment: @LaBird Ah, maybe to be more rigorous I should include a list of words that are not balanced :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Addition of even<->odd alphabets positions as they appear in aphanumeric order...

GOLD,7,15,12,4=>19<->19 balanced

LEMONS,12,5,13,15,14,19=>39<->39 balanced

UNCOOKED,21,14,3,15,15,11,5,4=>44<->44 balanced

BORDERLINE,2,15,18,4,5,18,12,9,14,5=>51<->51 balanced

LILLIPUTIANS,12,9,12,12,9,16,21,20,9,1,14,19=>77<->77 balanced

COUNTERBALANCE, ---->balanced

PREDETERMINATION, ---->balanced

so the answer is :

> BACKGAMMON

to see how they balence:

> BACKGAMMON,2,1,3,11,7,1,13,13,15,14 => 40 <-> 40 Balanced

CHECKERS,3,8,5,3,11,5,18,19 => 37<->35   NOT BALANCED

CRIBBAGE,3,18,9,2,2,1,7,5 => 21<->26 NOT BALANCED

DOMINOES,4,15,9,13,15,5,19 => 47<->31 not balanced

Used following ref :

1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11 12 13

a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j   k  l  m

z  y  x  w  v  u  t  s  r  q   p  o  n

26 25 24 23 22 21 20 19 18 17  16 15 14

Comment: What I was working toward but you beat me too it....good job.  You might get some backlash for formatting.

Comment: @kaine i am new here.How can i put answer as that appears in yellow bar.I gave 4 spaces before my answer but it is looking grayed (i do it on stackoverflow for coding).

Comment: The yellow bar is done by putting ">!" in front of the line.  For some reason it seems to mess up if you do it for two lines in a row.  That is about all I know on spoiler tags.  Here I did it as a edit you can see how.

Comment: Correct! Another way of wording it is that the alternating sum of the letters equals zero: 7 - 15 +12 - 4= 0. I only used even length words too avoid situations where might have used ASCII encodings or something to calculate it (with even letters it works either way)